Open port X becomes filtered after port-forwarding
There is a device with an ip address of 172.31.1.122 that is connected to a switch (Scalance 8008) and the switch is connecte to a router (scalance s615 which I cannot configure and has ip of 172.31.1.254). I want to access the data in general through our 5G industrian network (it is not a public network and completely internal).
When I connect my laptops lan socket directly to the switch, I can ping the device and when I scan it with nmap the port 502 appears open.
I have connected a 5G router(MU Scalance 856-1) to a setup shown in the below diagram. The sim card of my router has an ip of 172.16.1.32, and in the router I have defined a port forwarding from 172.16.1.32:502 to 172.31.1.122:502.
In general I am sure that my configuration of port-forwarding is correct because I have done this before with a couple of other devices with the same 5G-router model.
However, when I scan this port with nmap (nmap 172.16.1.32 -p 502), it shows the port being filtered.
The problem is likely that the Sentron-Com shown in the diagram has a different gateway but I am not sure how to handle it since it is not something I can change.
Is there a way to make it work similar to when I direct my laptop directly to the switch beside the internal router?

There is also probably a possiblity using Source NAT but I am not sure how to configure it and what I should write in each field:


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


ip of 10.45.0.24, and in the router I have defined a port forwarding from 10.45.0.24:502 to 172.31.1.122:502

Pointless effort - since 10.0.0.0/8 is reserved for private networks, there's no way you can connect there over the public Internet.

when I scan this port with nmap (nmap 10.45.0.24 -p 502), it shows the port being filtered.

To be expected. When you try to connect to that IP:port from the router's LAN side, the router would need to explicitly support hairpin NAT to allow a connection from LAN over WAN-side port forwarding back to LAN. Short of that, you can only connect from the outside (which excludes the Internet, see above).
What is you actual goal? It might be possible to use the port forwarding from another connection inside the same wireless ISP, but it cannot work from the general Internet. Even if it works from the same ISP now, that may break at any time in the future when their setup changes.
A functional setup would likely need to include a VPN link. Since you cannot connect to that router, it would need to connect to another site with a public IP address.
Then you could use the VPN tunnel to access services on the remote network. Additionally, VPN would provide proper access security as exposing unhardened devices to the public Internet is a very bad idea.
[after comments] Since you seem to be using a private 5G campus network, there's actually no point in translating addresses (source NAT, destination/reverse NAT/port forwarding). Better use normal routing. On the upstream router (above the 856), point a route for 172.31.1.0/24 (just guessing the size) to 10.45.0.24, set the default route of the LAN devices to 172.31.1.254 and you're done.
[after heavy editing] That won't work. A router needs to have different IP subnets on its interfaces to route between. Nodes within the same, shared subnet require a bridge between them, but that might not be what you're after.
This basic setup would work:
Scalance 856 "upstream router":

downstream 5G interface: 10.45.0.1/24
static route: 172.31.1.0/24 via 10.45.0.24

Scalance S615 router:

upstream 5G interface: 10.45.0.24/24
LAN interface: 172.31.1.254/24
transparent routing, no NAT
default route: 0.0.0.0/0 via 10.45.0.1

Simatic/Sentron nodes:

IP address from 172.31.1.0/24
default gateway: 172.31.1.254


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I updated the question. The problem is the 5G network doesn't know where 172.31.1.122 is. Source NAT could be a solution right? I just don't know how to configure it. The device has a different gateway to that of my own router

Please use the linked chat.
